# Testing a file download in java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, selenium, download

I have to test a web application using Selenium.
The application has a link for downloading a file.
I've set a Firefox profile so that the browser is downloading the file without asking for confirmation. My (simplified) Java code is as follows:

```
    File file = new File("myPath");
    driver.findElement(By.id("file-link-download-")).click(); // the download start here
    // my test
    if(!file.exists()) fail("file does not exist");
```

My problem is that the download runs in another thread and when "my test" (if file.exists()) is performed the file is not yet downloaded. I can pack this in a method putting some delay, like this:

```
public boolean fileExists(File file) {

    try {// Just wait 1000 milliseconds to see if the file exists
        Thread.sleep(sleep);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
            }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
   return false;
}
```

But this is not nice and not enough. I think that the best way should be to have a separate thread with a timeout which watches if the file is already downloaded and then returns true or returns false if the timeout is there.

Which is the best way (the correct way) to deal with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at this article? http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: Yes, I know the article. But this is not my case. Anyway, thanks for the link

Comment: `FluentWait` was designed for just this...it's generic and thus supports this kind of thing...you are just duplicating code.... https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java

Comment: From the link that @jbx posted:  

*What are you planning to do with the downloaded file?*  

If your answer is **nothing**, then why are you going to download it?  Whatever servlet is generating the file for download should be unit-tested independently.  Using any browser-automation framework to just click a link and see that it downloads a file isn't the cheapest way of verifying that a link doesn't 404 - there are far cheaper ways of verifying that.

Comment: @Roshan: Although I agree with you I have to download the files because I don't have a direct link to them. This UI relays in heavy JS stuff. I can perform a "click" at a DIV (in fact at a SPAN) and then a file got downloaded. Actually I don't really care about the performance of this test but on the result of the test.

Comment: If you open the network tab within the Chrome inspector, you'll see what direct link is being triggered to download the file when you click the DIV element.  Only use the browser to test what absolutely needs a browser.  Test everything else in a smaller, more appropriate unit-test.

Comment: @Roshan: Sure, but the link is dynamic.

Comment: @Arran: Thanks. The FluentWait is working perfect. +1 for you.

Comment: @Arran Please express your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @user270349, thanks for the reminder. Have done as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FluentWait` class is designed for conditions like this. I noticed that you were just, essentially, attempting to duplicate what had already been done in this class.

Below is the source of it:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java

It's very generic, and therefore can handle all kinds of different conditions - yours included.

All you'd need to do is just check `file.exists()` within the `apply` method, as shown within the sample documentation:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html